# WordPress - Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page

Tags: installation

1. I installed a clean WordPress with Version 6.2.2.
2. I installed the CiviCRM from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.62.1-wordpress.zip
3. After I click on activate the plugin I get a short time the attached screenshot and then I get the message 
   **Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page.**
   [image: Text]
4. Notice: I looked in the database and the tables for CiviCRM were not created

Can someone help me with my problemm please ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution was:

1. Delete WordPress and Database (Before I have used table_prefix=civicrm_)
2. Create new database with table_prefix=ccrm_
3. Install wordpress via terminal
4. Install CiviCRM via terminal and unzip
5. Set folder permission /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/ to 0777
6. Activate plugin CiviCRM and follow the instructions
7. Set folder permission /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/ back to 0755

### **Now, how can I install the GERMAN translation ???**

I can´t find a civicrm-x.x.x-l10n.tar.gz file on https://civicrm.org/download as described on https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/#install-localization-files-optional

Comment: The solution of the German translation I get from https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/wikis/Administrator-Guide#civicrm-installation-in-another-language-than-us-english

Comment: I have downloaded the translations from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.62.1-l10n.tar.gz and uploaded only the de_DE translation to the necessary folders as described in the doku

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CiviCRM. Did you run the installer as described in the [Installation Docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same way as described in the Docs.
I also Have changed the permission of the directory "/wp-content/plugins/civicrm" to 0777.

I think the Requirements check is successful but then I get the message
**Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page**.